# Word for a being smarter than a normal person

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word for sentient beings that are smarter than ordinary human beings. This word should at least include the following:

- Geniuses with artificially enhanced intelligence
- Alien lifeforms that are smarter than normal human beings
- A.I.s that are smarter than normal human beings

The words "overmind" and "posthuman" have come to my mind, but "overmind" seems to be generally understood as "being controlling other beings", while "posthuman" doesn't include super-smart aliens.

**Edit:** Fixed misleading wording.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're talking about is called superintelligence or hyperintelligence: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superintelligence

Comment: I think that Wikipedia page is just so much waffle. Neither *superintelligence* nor *hyperintelligence* have any commonly-understood meaning.

Comment: Fair enough. At the very least it's a place to start a synonym search.

Comment: To be honest, I think the question is effectively unanswerable. We can't even propose things like [suprahuman intelligence](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22suprahuman+intelligence%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), because that would exclude "unusually intelligent" human geniuses - a category OP explicitly says he wants covered by the target expression. I can't really imagine there's a special word for *more intelligent than an "ordinary" genius, but not so intelligent that no human being could ever be that smart*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I think the OP /was/ looking for something implying "no human being could ever be that smart".  It seemed like he was describing a human being who was not fully human in one way or another, e.g. genetically enhanced.  I interpreted that to mean that an ordinary human, even one with off-the-charts IQ who graduates college at the age of 9 or whatever, would not fall under that description.

Comment: @andi: I'm sure there are already "genetically-enhanced" people, if you include those born with genetic *defects* that have been *fixed/enhanced*. At what point do we start saying a person is "no longer human", just because they've had their genes tinkered with?

Comment: yeah, genetically enhanced (or "genetically modified") doesn't have a specific meaning.  But I was just giving my interpretation of the original question as the OP intended, not trying to dissect the meaning of genetically enhanced.

Comment: OP here. The answer is pretty much what I was looking for, and I did have the sort of intelligence in mind that goes beyond, and excludes, "natural genius". (Yeah, okay, my question was misleadingly worded. When I said "unusual intelligence", I meant "not natural".)